# Observer method called multiple time even if I register in viewWillAppear and unregister in viewWillDissapear

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsnotificationcenter

The observer method is being called multiple times even if I registered in viewWillAppear and unregistered in viewWillDissapear.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(handlePushNotification(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "abc"),
                                           object: nil)

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "abc"), object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the notification is being posted multiple times.

Comment: @CatalinaT. it shouldn't be a problem with a retain cycle.  viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear are independent of allocation and deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use-case for a member variable with a property observer: just make the notification observer a member of your View Controller subclass and handle the cleanup of the notification observer inside a willSet block:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var notificationObserver: Any? {
        willSet {
            // if notificationObserver is not null, unregister it
            if let observer = notificationObserver {
                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        notificationObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(handlePushNotification(notification:)),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "abc"),
                                       object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        notificationObserver = nil
    }

}
```

This will ensure the existing observer is *always* unregistered when a new one is created.

If you're still getting multiple callbacks, it will mean that the notification is being sent more than once.

Comment: Your logic would be ok, if the ```viewWillAppear``` is called multiple times on the same instance of viewController, which is not the case. Since the viewWillAppear calls are balanced with viewWillDisappear cals, the subscribe/unsubscribe calls are ok. The most probable cause of the poster is the notification is sent multiple times by the notifier.